# Run the Abaqus inp file using Python code

Tags: python, abaqus

I am a beginner in Python and coding. I wrote a Python code using Chatgpt to modify an initial Abaqus Python script and then run the modified inp file. I have a problem with this code and I don't know how I should fix it. At the end of the Python code, I wrote a code to run the modified inp, but when I run the Python code the inp file isn't run, and I don't see any changes. I want to run the modified inp file with Abaqus software( without opening the Abaqus) by Python code. Does anyone know what should I do? I attached the code here.

```
import shutil
import os
import subprocess
def delete_lines_in_range(file_path, start_line, end_line):
    with open(file_path, 'r+') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        file.seek(0)  # Move the file pointer to the beginning
        for i, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):
            if i < start_line or i > end_line:
                file.write(line)
        file.truncate()  # Remove the content after the modified lines

def add_text_after_line(file_path, line_number, text_to_add):
    with open(file_path, 'r+') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        if 0 < line_number <= len(lines):
            existing_line = lines[line_number - 1].strip()
            if "*Node" in existing_line:
                modified_line = existing_line.replace("*Node", "*Node" + text_to_add)
                lines[line_number - 1] = modified_line + "\n"

        file.seek(0)  # Move the file pointer to the beginning
        file.writelines(lines)

def add_text_before_heading(file_path, lines_to_add):
    with open(file_path, 'r+') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

        # Find the line number of the *Heading line
        heading_line_number = None
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if line.strip() == "*Heading":
                heading_line_number = i
                break

        if heading_line_number is not None:
            # Insert the lines before the *Heading line
            lines_to_add.reverse()  # Reverse the order to maintain correct insertion
            for line_to_add in lines_to_add:
                lines.insert(heading_line_number, line_to_add + "\n")

            file.seek(0)  # Move the file pointer to the beginning
            file.writelines(lines)

def replace_text_at_line(file_path, line_number, old_text, new_text):
    with open(file_path, 'r+') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        if 0 < line_number <= len(lines):
            lines[line_number - 1] = lines[line_number - 1].replace(old_text, new_text)

        file.seek(0)  # Move the file pointer to the beginning
        file.writelines(lines)

def save_as_new_file(original_file_path, new_file_path):
    shutil.copy(original_file_path, new_file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp_file_path = "D:/Majid/Solder Project-LG/2023-05-25-Final simulation/My script/Initial-job.inp"
    new_inp_file_path = "D:/Majid/Solder Project-LG/2023-05-25-Final simulation/My script/New folder/1.inp"
   
    start_line_number = 21073
    end_line_number = 43872
    delete_lines_in_range(inp_file_path, start_line_number, end_line_number)

    target_line_number = 21072
    text_to_add = ",input=prepreg_node#5.inp"
    add_text_after_line(inp_file_path, target_line_number, text_to_add)

    lines_to_add = [
        "*Parameter",
        "H0=-3.584715",
        "H1=-2.58471498731195",
        "B0=-6.212132",
        "B1=-5.34927579022115",
    ]
    add_text_before_heading(inp_file_path, lines_to_add)

    replace_text_at_line(inp_file_path, 235059, "-3.584715", "<H0>")
    replace_text_at_line(inp_file_path, 235060, "-3.584715", "<H0>")
    replace_text_at_line(inp_file_path, 235060, "-2.58471498731195", "<H1>")
    replace_text_at_line(inp_file_path, 235054, "-6.212132", "<B0>")
    replace_text_at_line(inp_file_path, 235055, "-6.212132", "<B0>")
    replace_text_at_line(inp_file_path, 235055, "-5.34927579022115", "<B1>")

    lines_to_add = [
        "delta=6",
        "Hx=H0+delta",
        "Hy=H1+delta",
        "Bx=B0+delta",
        "By=B1+delta",
    ]
    add_text_before_heading(inp_file_path, lines_to_add)

    replace_text_at_line(inp_file_path, 235064, "<H0>", "<Hx>")
    replace_text_at_line(inp_file_path, 235065, "<H0>", "<Hx>")
    replace_text_at_line(inp_file_path, 235065, "<H1>", "<Hy>")
    replace_text_at_line(inp_file_path, 235059, "<B0>", "<Bx>")
    replace_text_at_line(inp_file_path, 235060, "<B0>", "<Bx>")
    replace_text_at_line(inp_file_path, 235060, "<B1>", "<By>")

    save_as_new_file(inp_file_path, new_inp_file_path)

# Code to run the Abaqus inp file with 10 processors
def run_abq_inp_with_processors(inp_file, num_processors):
    abaqus_command = f"abaqus job={inp_file} cpus={num_processors}"
    try:
        subprocess.run(abaqus_command, shell=True, check=True)
        print(f"Job {inp_file} completed successfully with {num_processors} processors.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error running job {inp_file} with {num_processors} processors.")
        print(e)

# Replace '1.inp' with your actual inp file name
inp_file_name = "1.inp"
num_processors = 10

run_abq_inp_with_processors(inp_file_name, num_processors)
```

I modified the end part of the code several times where is written about the running the inp file, but i couldn't manage the code and simulation. In the Abaqus CAE when a inp file is submitted, after running some file appears, like ( odb, msg,dat,...) file. But when I run this code i don't see any of them. I want to run the modified inp file without opening the abaqus software using a Python code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your command to submit the job.
Usually, we should always pass `inp=<input file name>.inp` option and `job=<jobname>` option. However, if you just pass the `job` option with input file name, this will also work. (Case 1) 
**Case 1:** command is shown below:

```
abaqus job=1.inp cpus=10
```

In this case, Abaqus takes job name as `1` and input file name as `1.inp`
**Case 2:** (similar to what you have written)
However, if give full path to `job` option, then it'll throw an error. This error you can find in the log file the working folder. In this case, the log file name will be `1.log`.

```
abaqus job="D:/Majid/Solder Project-LG/2023-05-25-Final simulation/My script/1.inp" cpus=10
```

So, use both option `job` as well as `inp` as follows:

```
abaqus job=1 inp="D:/Majid/Solder Project-LG/2023-05-25-Final simulation/My script/1.inp" cpus=10
```

You just change `run_abq_inp_with_processors` function as below:

```
import os
def run_abq_inp_with_processors(inp_path, num_processors):
    # get the input file name from the path
    inp_fnm = os.path.basename(inp_path)
    
    # Extract input file name without .inp --> job name
    job_name = os.path.splitext(inp_fnm)[0]
    abaqus_command = f'abaqus job={job_name} inp="{inp_path}" cpus={num_processors}'

    try:
        subprocess.run(abaqus_command, shell=True, check=True)
        print(f"Job {job_name} completed successfully with {num_processors} processors.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error running job {job_name} with {num_processors} processors.")
        print(e)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have modified the code as below but it doesn't work yet. 
def run_abq_inp_with_processors(inp_path, num_processors):
    inp_fnm = os.path.basename("D:/Majid/Solder Project-LG/2023-05-25-Final simulation/My script/New folder/1.inp")
    
    # Extract input file name without .inp --> job name
    job_name = os.path.splitext(inp_fnm)[0]
    abaqus_command = f'abaqus job=1 inp="1.inp" cpus=10'

Comment: Could you please check the error in the `1.log` file and let me know??

Comment: There is no such file. As I already mentioned, the inp file is not run and no file is created.

Comment: Try this: 1. Confirm you are running the script in the same folder as input file. 2. Try running the command in from cmd first (as explained in the ans). And then use same command here.